# Change data format in Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica. I'n using the online trial version12.1. I have got a sample data like

```
result =Import["/wolframcloud/userfiles/../data/data.csv"]

>> {{1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1}}
```

But I want data format like {1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1} because I need to do transpose later. So how can I achieve this? What is the difference between {{}} and {}? Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So in this case, {{1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1}} means a list contains the list which is {1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1}?

Comment: Thanks so much! you perfectly solve my problem